# Add names to tables in Tableau

Tags: csv, tableau-api

I'm new to Tableau and now have a CSV file without column names. All data are stored in this CSV file. There is another CSV file contains all column names. I am trying to add these names to the unnamed data file. Is there a way to do it? 
I know I could open the CSV file and copy the name manually, but I wish I could operate it in the Tableau.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can connect to a CSV file that does not have a header row, and then name the fields yourself in Tableau when editing the data connection.

Click on the settings (gear shaped) icon on the right side of the table in the data source pane.
[image]

Then specify that there is no header row and that Tableau should generate names for the fields.
[image]

Then rename the fields from their generated names like F2, F2 etc to something meaningful, by clicking on the little black triangle icon next to the generated field names and choosing rename.

Comment: Glad to hear it. BTW, the SO way to say thanks is to accept the answer.